# View terms and conditions without losing form inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that allows users to view some terms and conditions, which causes them to leave the current page. When they come back, the form is blank.

How can I store their inputs so they don't lose what they've already entered?

I would rather avoid popups if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the link to the Terms and Conditions open in a new tab/window (`target="_blank"`), or you could use a modal dialog to overlay the *Terms and Conditions* info in the same page.

I don't know Ruby/RoR though.

Answer (score 1):

If the term and condition is mandatory, why don't you load it in the first place and then you can easily manipulate it using lightbox/fancybox or simple javascript.